# Selenium Webdriver for IE XPath - c#

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Im using Selenium Webdriver for IE

I am having trouble sending a click to an image. The particular image is used throughout the page - I am attempting to find by xPath.

The html snippet:

`<img src='Option.gif' border='0' style="cursor:hand;" onClick="javascript:DropDownOpen('ID_1_0_0_3_0_19');"  />`

The Webdriver Code:

`driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//img[contains(@onClick, \"javascript:DropDownOpen('ID_1_0_0_3_0_19');\"]")).Click();`

Answer (score 0):

Your having a problem clicking the image because your xpath contains single quotes. To xpath to an element with single quotes you'll want to use xpath's concat() function. Your xpath becomes

```
//img[@onClick=concat('javascript:DropDownOpen(',"'",'ID_1_0_0_3_0_19',"'",');')]
```

You'll notice we concat `javascript:DropDownOpen(` in single quotes and anytime we need to target an element containing a single quote we wrap them in double quotes.

Happy Xpathing!